# Wrap xlabels in Seaborn Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, axis-labels

Have been trying to modify me plot such that the xlabels can be wrapped.
Have looked at few suggestions from similar questions.
But am unable to use them on this.
The ax.set_xticklabels code does not wrap the labels.
The plt.xticks code throws an error -
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'

```
plt.figure(figsize = (7,5))
ax = sns.countplot(data = df3, x = df3.PaymentMethod, hue = df3.Churn)
#ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), ha="right", horizontalalignment = 'center', wrap = True)
plt.xticks([textwrap.fill(label, 10) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()], 
           rotation = 10, fontsize=8, horizontalalignment="center")
```

Image of plot with overlapping xlabels
[image]

Comment: Maybe `textwrap.fill(label.get_text(), 10)`?  The label itself is a matplotlib object which also contains coloring and position information.

Comment: I guess it's easier to provide wrapped texts to the plotting function (`x=df3.PaymentMethod.apply(lambda x: textwrap.fill(x, 10))`)

Answer (score 5):

[`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) works as expected with the code suggested in the comments:

```
import numpy as np     # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd    # v 1.1.3
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.0
import textwrap

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)
cat_names = ['Short name', 'Slightly longer name', 'Rather much longer name',
             'Longest name of them all by far']
counts = rng.integers(10, 100, len(cat_names))
var_cat = np.repeat(cat_names, counts)
var_bool = rng.choice(['True', 'False'], size=len(var_cat))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(vcat=var_cat, vbool=var_bool))

# Plot seaborn countplot with wrapped tick labels
ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x='vcat', hue='vbool')
labels = [textwrap.fill(label.get_text(), 12) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
```

[image: textwrap_ticklabels]